# Save an Image in database with written text in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It shows the text on Image but don't save in database. The previous image without text is saved in db.

Can you help to save text also on Image in db.

```
public void ImageText()
{
            Image bitmap = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Image/IMG_20160930_082316.jpg"));
            //draw the image object using a Graphics object
            Graphics graphicsImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            //Set the alignment based on the coordinates   
            StringFormat stringformat = new StringFormat();
            stringformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            stringformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            StringFormat stringformat2 = new StringFormat();
            stringformat2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringformat2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            //Set the font color/format/size etc..  
            Color StringColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#933eea");//direct color adding
            Color StringColor2 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e80c88");//customise color adding
            string Str_TextOnImage = "Hello";//Your Text On Image
            string Str_TextOnImage2 = "Word";//Your Text On Image
            graphicsImage.DrawString(Str_TextOnImage, new Font("arial", 40,
            FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(StringColor), new Point(268, 245),
            stringformat); Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            graphicsImage.DrawString(Str_TextOnImage2, new Font("Edwardian Script ITC", 111,
            FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(StringColor2), new Point(145, 255),
            stringformat2); Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

[This is an Normal Image without text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1lJa.jpg)

[After Add Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtsYz.png)

but can't save Text Image in to DB. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted is only about the adding text on the bitmap object and saving the bitmap object back to physical file on which the text is added. There is no code to save this image in DB.

Comment: Can you help me to do this ?

Comment: It's pretty simple, depending on which objects you are using to save the data in DB. You just update the table field with binary data of your bitmap object.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Post method for Image upload
     [HttpPost]
            public async Task<JsonResult> AddPromotion(AddPromotionDto addpromotions)
            {
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                        string promotionImage;
                        addpromotions.PromotionImage = file.FileName;
                        promotionImage = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("../Image/"), addpromotions.PromotionImage);
                        file.SaveAs(promotionImage);
                        using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            using (var oldImage = new Bitmap(file.InputStream))
                            {
                                var format = oldImage.RawFormat;
                                string fileName = promotionImage;
                                using (var newImage = ResizeImage(oldImage, 800, 2000))
                                {
                                    Graphics graphicsImage = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
                                    StringFormat stringformat = new StringFormat();
                                    stringformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                                    stringformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
                                    StringFormat stringformat2 = new StringFormat();
                                    stringformat2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                    stringformat2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                    Color StringColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e80c88");
                                    string Str_TextOnImage = addpromotions.PromotionName;
                                    graphicsImage.DrawString(Str_TextOnImage, new Font("arial", 40,
                                    FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(StringColor), new Point(500, 300),
                                    stringformat);
                                    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                                    newImage.Save(fileName, format); // for overwrite the previous image
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                await companyManager.AddPromotion(User.Identity.Name, addpromotions);
                return Json("Promotions", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }


    // Method for resize the image
     public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, int width, int height)
            {
                if (image.Width <= width && image.Height <= height)
                {
                    return image;
                }
                int newWidth;
                int newHeight;
                if (image.Width > image.Height)
                {
                    newWidth = width;
                    newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ((float)width / image.Width));
                }
                else
                {
                    newHeight = height;
                    newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ((float)height / image.Height));
                }
                var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {
                    graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                    return newImage;
                }
            }
```